# Search keywords in mysql and get data which have minimum 5 keywords

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a large database in which various images are saved.

Each image has multiple keywords split by `comma(,)`.

Now some images are showing on the front end when user click the image it will show images which have at least 5 common keywords with the selected keywords. I am confused how to do it.

Comment: Don't store multiple keywords in a single column. use a mapping table

Comment: i am working on client site. I dont create the database so i have to do as it is.

Comment: OK, then expand your question to get an answer. Please add your table structure, example data, expected output and the query you are stuck with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all get all keywords of the image to whome you want to search like you clicked on image one whose keywords are :

```
$keywords = "good,beautiful,nice,weather";
```

Now add loop to get all keywords in an array by explode.

```
$exploded = explode(",",$keywords);
```

Now use foreach loop on `$exploded` to match from db.

use your query like this

```
$matched = array();
foreach($exploded as $key => $searchValue) 
{   
    select * from cars where colors like '%,$searchValue,%';
    //you can use find in set instead like:
    select * from cars where find_in_set($searchValue,colors);

    //code here to check matched or not.
   //if result matched add 1 in count of same index in matched array like :
   $matchedimageid = //get image id from query and add that in array.
   $matched[$matchedimageid] = $matched[$matchedimageid]+1;
}

//code here to get all image ids from $matched array whose value greater than or equal to 5. and show them in list
```

Note: this logic is for your current situation but best solution is to have keywords in seperate table.